# Something that cause plain iframe not to show on php page?

Tags: php, iframe

```
<div class="grid-5-12">
<iframe width="200" height="120" src="http://www.saweb.info/videos/nightclub.mp4" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

I copied above direct from an "admin page" from Firefox developer page source and it works as standalone, but on the admin page itself it doesn't appear (it always did)

It also doesn't show even without the div. (It's in a parsley form and the iframe show the "current selected video")

Tested in Chrome and it also doesn't display while I can't find any similar error on the internet.

Anyone perhaps has an idea why the iframe don't appear / disappeared please?

Comment: Are you testing the page locally or on a webpage?

Comment: Server side it always worked but not now. Locally it still works but the solution from Robin Rai solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

is not used for play videos but to display another page. Some browsers might support this way of importing a video. But correct way to use  tag like this for your video link.

```
<video width="200" height="120" controls>
  <source src="http://www.saweb.info/videos/nightclub.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. The iframe actually worked for a long time until recently.